# Grid from text to 2d array

Tags: java, grid

```
  import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;




public class FileInputExample2
{



static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  int t;
    BufferedReader filein;
    filein = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("GridDATA.txt"));
   int intGrid [] [] = new int [10] [10];
    String inputLine = filein.readLine();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, " ");

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {String eachNumber = st.nextToken();
      intGrid [i] [j] = Integer.parseInt(eachNumber);
    }
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
     for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      System.out.println( intGrid[i][j]);
    }

  }
}
```

this is what i have so far im trying to display this grid that i have the text file looks like this :

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

I have no idea why its not wokring. ultimatly i wil be makin a maze.

Comment: Notepad is an application, what you want is to convert from text, I edited to make the question more clear.

Comment: i have to use the text file specificed. I just need to display the numbers in the file onto the application.

Comment: Is this homework?  And print your result so we can more easily see what's busted.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `System.out.println( intGrid[i][j]);` will print one grid element per line.

You probably want something more like

```
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
         {
         System.out.print( intGrid[i][j]);
         System.out.print(" ");
         }
     System.out.println("");
     }
```

Note that we're using `print` in the inner loop, not println. This will not perform a carriage return so the numbers will be on one line.  After the inner loop, however, we execute a `println` to perform the carriage return/newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FileInputExample2 {

    static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader filein = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GridDATA.txt"));
        int intGrid[][] = new int[10][10];
        Scanner st = new Scanner(filein);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                intGrid[i][j] = st.nextInt();
        }

        for (int[] arr1d : intGrid)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1d));

    }
}
```